# What causes no display and no USB connection on my Anycubic Chiron?

Tags: usb, anycubic-chiron, mightyboard, display

I have an Anycubic Chiron with a Trigorilla controller board with a chip labeled **ATmega2560 16U TW 355e3f 1833amw** - However I could not find a link to the board, and there is no more info than **Trigorilla** on it. The power supply seems to work fine - green LED on, fan on. The middle piece has a red LED labeled "DC" in red.

My problem is that the board seems to not work. I just installed it. You can see all the connections in the photos. The display does not light up. My connected PC does not recognize a USB input either. I have installed the driver of the printer on the official Anycubic website prior to testing. I have not restarted my computer though - but the display should light up anyway, I figured.

[image: Close up photo of Trigorilla controller board]

[image: Close up photo of Trigorilla controller board]

[image: Close up photo of Trigorilla controller board]

[image: Close up photo of Trigorilla controller board]

[image: Close up photo of Trigorilla controller board]

[image: Close up photo of Trigorilla controller board]

[image: Close up photo of Trigorilla controller board]

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably a power issue, no power to the display is an important hint. Note that if the power supply unit (PSU) shows a green LED, it doesn't imply that the PSU is working.

The Trigorilla board can still be found in various online shops, this isn't an uncommon board.

Furthermore, you should look into the fuses and measure them through with a multimeter; although these are recoverable fuses according to the [documenttion](https://printers-3d.co/products/anycubic-motherboard-3d-printer-trigorilla-main-board-compatible-mega-2560-ramps1-4-4-layers-pcb-controller-board-for-reprap):

> **Voltage input at super wide range, short-circuit protection:**
>
> TriGorilla adopts DC - DC step-down scheme design and Recoverable fuse for short-circuit protection, improving the MEGA2560 board serious heating problem,
>
> Allowing any power supply from 10 V-30 V.

There are reported issues with the fuses being blown and not recovering.

In order to figure out what the problem is you need to do some troubleshooting. Measure the fuses (note that in case the fuses are unrecoverably blown, you need to find out why; as replacing them without fixing the short will blow them again), use a different power supply, or test the power supply on a different device where several amps are drwan, e.g. directly heat the heated bed from the PSU for a short while.